# Property 'ref' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, any>' but required in type 'ReactSVGElement'.ts(2741)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello not understanding this error... i really dont want to just use //@ts-ignore either. The code compiles fines on the ui as well.

HOC component for input where we can include a Icon prop as so

```js
import { ReactSVGElement, ChangeEventHandler } from "react";

interface InputProps {
  htmlFor: string,
  labelClass: string,
  labelName?: string, 
  icon: ReactSVGElement,
  defaultValue?: string,
  type: string,
  name: string,
  id: string, 
  autoComplete?: string,
  inputClass?: string,
  disabled?: boolean,
  onChange:  ChangeEventHandler,
}
```

```js
export default function Input ({onChange, htmlFor, labelClass, labelName, icon, defaultValue, disabled, type, name, id, autoComplete, inputClass}: InputProps) {
  return (
    <label
      htmlFor={htmlFor}
      className={labelClass}
    >
      {icon}
      {labelName}
      <input
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        id={id}
        disabled
        autoComplete={autoComplete}
        className={inputClass}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </label>
  )
}
```

when using the component in the parent file the icon prop is underlined red with the TS error when hovered. not sure where i would include ref at this point.

from the parent file

```js
<Input
  htmlfor="first-name"
  labelClass="flex items-center text-md font-bold" 
  icon={<PencilIcon className="h-6 w-6 mr-1"/>}
  labelName='Name'
  defaultValue={userName}
  type="text"
  name="first-name"
  id="first-name" 
  autoComplete="first-name"
  inputClass="justify-self-end ml-3 mt-1 block w-full border border-gray-300"  
/>
```

The error from ts is

```
(property) InputProps.icon: ReactSVGElement
Property 'ref' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, any>' but required in type 'ReactSVGElement'.ts(2741)
index.d.ts(175, 9): 'ref' is declared here.
index.tsx(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'icon' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'
```

Comment: It appears that your instance of PencilIcon should have a ref property defined?

Comment: i thought so too but hero doesnt require a ref in their docs. somewhere in the icon: ReactSVGElement, creation that ReactSVGElement is missing a ref here.